# How to add class on specific div when scroll?

Tags: javascript, css, panel

I am playing around and practice my JS (beginner). I have created stacking panels and i hit a wall. I just can not target and add class of shadow to the moving element (only when one panel is above other, class should add).
For now i have this:

```js
const boxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".box"));
    const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
    const leftMargin = 60; //px

    function scrollWrap(e) {
        let scrollCoord = wrapper.scrollLeft; // horizontal scroll value
        
        boxes.forEach((box, index) => {
            let leftMarginStop = index * leftMargin;
            const boxCoord = box.getBoundingClientRect();
            let leftCoordPanel = boxCoord.left;
            let flag = false;
            
            
            //console.log({scrollCoord, leftMarginStop, leftCoordPanel, box});
            if (boxCoord.left <= leftMarginStop) { // if left side of pannel is less than margin 60, 120, 180,... 
                //console.log("STAHP!!");
                box.style.position = "sticky";
                box.style.left = `${leftMarginStop}px`; // sets the left to 60, 120, 180,...
                flag = true;
                
                if (flag) {
                    box.classList.add("shadow");
                    console.log(this) //how to target each panel rather than wrapper?
                } else {
                    box.classList.remove("shadow");
                }
                
            } else {
                box.style.position = "static";
                box.style.left = 0;
                flag = false;
            }
        });
    }
    
wrapper.addEventListener("scroll", scrollWrap);
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
} 
.wrapper, .box1, .box2, .box3, .box4, .box5, .box6, .box7, .box8 {
    position: sticky;
    height: 750px;
    z-index: 1;
} 
.wrapper {
    width: 1442px;
    border-right: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    display: flex;
    overflow: scroll;
}  
.wrapper .box1 {
    min-width: 357px;
    height: 750px;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
.wrapper .box2 {
    min-width: 357px;
    height: 750px;
    background-color: #333;
}
.wrapper .box3 {
    min-width: 702px;
    height: 750px;
    background-color: #4d4d4d;
}
.wrapper .box4 {
    min-width: 630px;
    height: 750px;
    background-color: #666;
}
.wrapper .box5 {
    min-width: 630px;
    height: 750px;
    background-color: #808080;
}
.wrapper .box6 {
    min-width: 357px;
    height: 750px;
    background-color: #999;
}
.wrapper .box7 {
    min-width: 630px;
    height: 750px;
    background-color: #b3b3b3;
}
.wrapper .box8 {
    min-width: 630px;
    height: 750px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.shadow {
    box-shadow: -4px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);   
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="box box1"></div>
 <div class="box box2"></div>
 <div class="box box3"></div>
 <div class="box box4"></div>
 <div class="box box5"></div>
 <div class="box box6"></div>
 <div class="box box7"></div>
 <div class="box box8"></div>
</div>
```

If anyone can help me out, please show me code with explanation, so i can see and know what and how.
I try to do it with some flag or without, but every time the class is added when element reaches the end (left padding). I want to add class when element is on top of other element. If it is not, remove class. Also, how to make this so it works on mouse scroll wheel? I was testing this with apple magic mouse, but on scroll wheel it does not work.
Oh and please, if you see something very wrong please let me know, i am beginner and would like to learn something from this post.

Comment: getting around the filter is not the best thing... post the code in the question. Use a snipplet which allow you to have the same functionality that is in jsfiddle. https://i.stack.imgur.com/522IS.png

Comment: Also, its "oh" , not "ow" ! :)

Comment: Done ;). Thank you, i did not see that.

Answer (score 0):

**Tips for your code:**

1. In your `CSS` code, the `wrapper` element has a `width` property. This
   causes the page and the `wrapper` element to have a `scrollbars`. So,
   remove it.
2. You do not need to use `javascript` to add stickiness to the
   boxes. The only `CSS` will do this for you. You need JavaScript only
   for add the `left` property and `shadow` to the boxes.
3. Don’t try to use `overflow: auto|scroll|hidden` on the parent element
   of a `position:sticky` element. It completely breaks the stickiness.
   `overflow: visible` is fine. See the code snippet below.
4. In your JavaScript code, the `flag` variant value, always is true, So
   the `shadow` class can't remove from elements.

**Other notes:**

5. If you’re wanting to use `position:absolute` on an element inside of
   a sticky element you have to be careful. If your app is running in
   an older browser that doesn’t support `position:sticky`, then that
   sticky element won’t act like a `relative` positioned element. So
   the `absolute` positioned element will skip it and look up the DOM
   tree until it finds the next `non-static` element `(absolute / relative / fixed position)`, defaulting to the html element if none
   found. In other words, your `absolute` positioned element is going
   to be in a way different place on the screen than you expected it to
   be.
6. `position: sticky;` is supported in a lot of browsers, but not yet
   in `Edge`. `IE` doesn’t matter at this point. There are many
   `polyfills` out there if you absolutely have to have this behavior,
   but they all use JavaScript. A better option is to design your app
   so that sticky position is a slick addition, but the app still
   functions without it.

**Example:**

```js
const boxes = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( '.box' ) ),
      scroller = document.querySelector( '.scroller' ),
      leftMargin = 30,
      length = boxes.length - 1;

function scrollWrap() {
    boxes.forEach( function( box, index ) {
        let leftMarginStop = index * leftMargin;
        const boxCoord = box.getBoundingClientRect();
        let leftCoordPanel = boxCoord.left;

        if ( leftCoordPanel <= leftMarginStop ) {
            box.style.left = leftMarginStop + 'px';
            if ( index < length ) boxes[ index + 1 ].classList.add( 'shadow' )
            if ( index == 0 && boxes[ 1 ].getBoundingClientRect().left == box.offsetWidth ) boxes[ 1 ].classList.remove( 'shadow' )
        } else {
            box.style.left = 0;
            if ( index < length ) boxes[ index + 1 ].classList.remove( 'shadow' )
        }
    } );
}

scroller.addEventListener( 'scroll', scrollWrap )
```

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%
}
.scroller {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden
}
.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex
}
.box {
    min-width: 630px;
    height: 100%;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    left: 0 /* <-- become sticky once touching left edge */
}
.box1 {
    min-width: 357px;
    background: #1a1a1a url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/10/16/09/seamless-pattern-1086662__340.jpg)
}
.box2 {
    min-width: 357px;
    background: #333 url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/18/23/46/template-1099298__340.png)
}
.box3 {
    min-width: 702px;
    background: #4d4d4d url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/07/28/16/00/pattern-403769__340.png)
}
.box4 {
    background: #666 url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/06/10/03/14/damask-2388884__340.png)
}
.box5 {
    background: #808080 url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/12/17/34/seamless-pattern-1089797__340.png)
}
.box6 {
    min-width: 357px;
    background: #999 url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/06/16/23/background-1240686__340.png)
}
.box7 {
    background: #b3b3b3 url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/04/24/05/00/backdrop-3346304__340.png)
}
.box8 {
    background: #ccc url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/01/09/03/floral-1299131__340.png)
}
.shadow {
    box-shadow: -10px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="scroller">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="box box1"></div>
        <div class="box box2"></div>
        <div class="box box3"></div>
        <div class="box box4"></div>
        <div class="box box5"></div>
        <div class="box box6"></div>
        <div class="box box7"></div>
        <div class="box box8"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## About your updated code:

the following line in your jS code:

```
const leftSideOfNextItem = box.nextElementSibling.getBoundingClientRect().left;
```

causes an error. Because, when `index` become 8, `box.nextElementSibling` can't retrieve any element. So you can change it to this:

```
const leftSideOfNextItem = ( index < boxes.length - 1 ) ? box.nextElementSibling.getBoundingClientRect().left : 0;
```

Also at the end of your JS code, the following code snippet:

```
if (index[4] && leftSideOfCurrent < leftMarginStop) {
  console.log("helo");
}
```

must change to:

```
// when panel 5 reach left margin, left margin change from 60 to 30 to all panels
if (index == 4 && leftSideOfCurrent <= leftMarginStop) {
  console.log("helo");
  leftMargin = 30
}
```

Also you must change `const leftMargin = 60;` to `var leftMargin = 60;`

**Updated code:**

```js
const boxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".box"));
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
var leftMargin = 60; //px

function scrollWrap(e) {
    let scrollCoord = wrapper.scrollLeft; // horizontal scroll value

    boxes.forEach((box, index) => {
        let leftMarginStop = (index) * leftMargin; // calculation for left margin stop (60, 120, 180,...)
        const boxCoord = box.getBoundingClientRect();
        const leftSideOfCurrent = boxCoord.left; // coordinarion of left side of panel
        const rightSideOfCurrent = boxCoord.right; // coordinarion of right side of panel
        const leftSideOfNextItem = ( index < boxes.length - 1 ) ? box.nextElementSibling.getBoundingClientRect().left: 0; // coordinarion of left side of NEXT panel

        box.style.position = "sticky";
        box.style.left = `${leftMarginStop}px`;

        // controll shadow of first element
        scrollCoord > 0 ? boxes[1].classList.add("shadow") : boxes[1].classList.remove("shadow");
        // controll shadow of all 0+ elements
        if (leftSideOfCurrent <= leftMarginStop) { // if left side of pannel is less than margin 60, 120, 180,... 
            box.nextElementSibling.classList.add("shadow");
        }
        // controll removal of shadow of all 0+ elements
        if (leftSideOfNextItem === rightSideOfCurrent) {
            box.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("shadow");  
        }
        // when panel 5 reach left margin, left margin change from 60 to 30 to all panels
        if (index == 4 && leftSideOfCurrent <= leftMarginStop) {
            console.log("helo");
            leftMargin = 30
        }
    });
}

wrapper.addEventListener("scroll", scrollWrap);
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
} 
.wrapper, .box0, .box1, .box2, .box3, .box4, .box5, .box6, .box7 {
    position: sticky;
    height: 750px;
    z-index: 1;
} 
.wrapper {
    width: 1442px;
    border-right: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    display: flex;
    overflow: scroll;
}  
.wrapper .box0 {
    min-width: 357px;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
.wrapper .box1 {
    min-width: 357px;
    background-color: #333;
}
.wrapper .box2 {
    min-width: 702px;
    background-color: #4d4d4d;
}
.wrapper .box3 {
    min-width: 630px;
    background-color: #666;
}
.wrapper .box4 {
    min-width: 630px;
    background-color: #808080;
}
.wrapper .box5 {
    min-width: 357px;
    background-color: #999;
}
.wrapper .box6 {
    min-width: 630px;
    background-color: #b3b3b3;
}
.wrapper .box7 {
    min-width: 630px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.shadow {
    box-shadow: -4px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.2);
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4,-0.01, 0, 0.98);
    -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4,-0.01, 0, 0.98);
    -o-transition: box-shadow 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4,-0.01, 0, 0.98);
    transition: box-shadow 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4,-0.01, 0, 0.98);
}
/* To make the console visible. */
.box0 {
  height: 700px;
)
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="box box0"></div>
        <div class="box box1"></div>
        <div class="box box2"></div>
        <div class="box box3"></div>
        <div class="box box4"></div>
        <div class="box box5"></div>
        <div class="box box6"></div>
        <div class="box box7"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just want to argument why i have done it, you can correct me:
1. I set width because i want to simulate window, and i want scrollbar. This was only way for me to get scrollbar. I see that you create scroller class as container and than wrapper to take 100% of container width
2. I know this can be all done with CSS, but i want to add JS because i will later do the hover when element is on left side, controll the shadows etc.

also i have updated my code a bit. But there are still questions i do not know answers. Look below please. And thank you for your reply

Comment: I have managed to update my code, please look my answer (to little characters to go here)

Answer (score 0):

For now i have managed to update my code. It works when i scroll and shadow is also applying to the panel. There is still something i wonder.

1. When i add shadow class i created transition. It works perfect, but when i remove shadow class it just disappears, no transition back. Why is that? I want shadow to appear and disappear in same way
2. How to track every single panel if it has reached the left margin, and than apply eventListener with mouse enter and mouse leave on it? So when i hover to "closed" panel, i get that item and if i hover on NOT "closed" panel i will not get item. I was trying with console.log "this" but it returned every panel i mouse entered it
3. How to target every panel, so i can later say, when 4th panel reaches left margin, the margin of stacked elements change?

My updated code:

```js
const boxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".box"));
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
const leftMargin = 60; //px

function scrollWrap(e) {
    let scrollCoord = wrapper.scrollLeft; // horizontal scroll value

    boxes.forEach((box, index) => {
        let leftMarginStop = (index) * leftMargin; // calculation for left margin stop (60, 120, 180,...)
        const boxCoord = box.getBoundingClientRect();
        const leftSideOfCurrent = boxCoord.left; // coordinarion of left side of panel
        const rightSideOfCurrent = boxCoord.right; // coordinarion of right side of panel
        const leftSideOfNextItem = box.nextElementSibling.getBoundingClientRect().left; // coordinarion of left side of NEXT panel

        box.style.position = "sticky";
        box.style.left = `${leftMarginStop}px`;

        // controll shadow of first element
        scrollCoord > 0 ? boxes[1].classList.add("shadow") : boxes[1].classList.remove("shadow");
        // controll shadow of all 0+ elements
        if (leftSideOfCurrent <= leftMarginStop) { // if left side of pannel is less than margin 60, 120, 180,... 
            box.nextElementSibling.classList.add("shadow");
        }
        // controll removal of shadow of all 0+ elements
        if (leftSideOfNextItem === rightSideOfCurrent) {
            box.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("shadow");  
        }
        // when panel 5 reach left margin, left margin change from 60 to 30 to all panels
        if (boxes[4] && leftSideOfCurrent < leftMarginStop) {
            console.log("helo");
        }
    });
}

wrapper.addEventListener("scroll", scrollWrap);
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
} 
.wrapper, .box1, .box2, .box3, .box4, .box5, .box6, .box7, .box8 {
    position: sticky;
    height: 750px;
    z-index: 1;
} 
.wrapper {
    width: 1442px;
    border-right: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    display: flex;
    overflow: scroll;
}  
.wrapper .box0 {
    min-width: 357px;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
.wrapper .box1 {
    min-width: 357px;
    background-color: #333;
}
.wrapper .box2 {
    min-width: 702px;
    background-color: #4d4d4d;
}
.wrapper .box3 {
    min-width: 630px;
    background-color: #666;
}
.wrapper .box4 {
    min-width: 630px;
    background-color: #808080;
}
.wrapper .box5 {
    min-width: 357px;
    background-color: #999;
}
.wrapper .box6 {
    min-width: 630px;
    background-color: #b3b3b3;
}
.wrapper .box7 {
    min-width: 630px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.shadow {
    box-shadow: -4px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.2);
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4,-0.01, 0, 0.98);
    -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4,-0.01, 0, 0.98);
    -o-transition: box-shadow 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4,-0.01, 0, 0.98);
    transition: box-shadow 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4,-0.01, 0, 0.98);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="box box0"></div>
        <div class="box box1"></div>
        <div class="box box2"></div>
        <div class="box box3"></div>
        <div class="box box4"></div>
        <div class="box box5"></div>
        <div class="box box6"></div>
        <div class="box box7"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was helpful. I know for error but could not fix it. I have set `let leftMargin = 60;` i use let instead var.
I am working on the margins, if the 5th panel reaches the left margin the margin of all panels get 30px. I did it also for reverse:

```js
if (index > 4 && leftSideOfCurrent <= leftMarginStop) {
    leftMargin = 30;
} else if (index < 5 && leftSideOfCurrent > leftMarginStop) {
    leftMargin = 60;
}
```

But now when 5th panel reaches left margin, the panels less than 5 get EACH transitioned seperately instead of all, but when the 5th element is no longer in left margin, all gets transitioned at same time. Why is it like that? I do not understand. Can you explain please?